# Strange behavior using def in groovy's repl (groovysh)

Tags: groovy, types, instantiation, read-eval-print-loop, groovysh

## Problem Summary

This morning I was using *groovysh* to test a closure but in the process of doing so I experience unexpected behavior  I defined a class in *groovysh* then instantiated an object from that class as follows

```
groovy:000> class Student {
groovy:001> def firstName
groovy:002> def lastName
groovy:003> }
===> true
groovy:000> def chris = new Student()
===> Student@52d239ba
```

I then tried to set the firstName attribute using an implicit setter method as follows:

```
groovy:000> chris.setFirstName("chris")
```

And received the following error

```
Unknown property: chris
```

I then tried to instantiate a new object without `def` it executed successfully

```
groovy:000> jen = new Student()
===> Student@c1bd0be
groovy:000> jen.setFirstName("Jenifer")
===> null
```

Not understanding why this was happening I then created an executable groovy file (as seen below)

```
class Student {
    def firstName
    def lastName
}

def chris = new Student()
chris.setFirstName("Christopher")
println chris


john = new Student()
john.setFirstName("Jonathan")
println john
```

I then executed the script and received the following output

```
Student@6ab778a
Student@1dac5ef
```

I found this very odd because the script threw an exception in groovysh but executed successfully as a standalone file.

My `groovy -v` is `Groovy Version: 2.6.0-alpha-2 JVM: 1.8.0_111 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Windows 10`, and I was running *groovysh* in Powershell with Administrator privileges.

I did a few minutes of research to better understand this anomaly but because the search terms (groovy, def, groovysh, repl, instantiation, exception, etc) are so common I was not able to find anything that explicitly addressed this behavior.

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is described on the `groovysh` [documentation page](http://www.groovy-lang.org/groovysh.html#GroovyShell-Variables):

> Shell variables are all untyped (i.e. no def or other type information).
>
> This will set a shell variable:
>
> ```
> foo = "bar"
> ```
>
> But, this will evaluate a local variable and will not be saved to the shell’s >environment:
>
> ```
> def foo = "bar"
> ```

You can enable [interpreter mode](http://www.groovy-lang.org/groovysh.html#GroovyShell-InterpreterMode) to change the behavior (type this in the `groovysh` console):

```
:set interpreterMode true
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.  If I'm reading this correctly, a variable instantiated with def will not be accessible further down in the shell, but a class initialized with def will be?  Is there a reason they did this?

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli I'm not sure I understand correctly. I suspect that this is because of how the context and evaluation of scripts is processed. I haven't seen the source of this, but I would assume that each command makes its own script and the code goes into the `run` method, which would exclude other local variables (and the shell would make exceptions for variables declared without `def` or specific data types).

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much for sharing your knowledge me with.